# Getting error C2440: char[]* to char* (pointers)

Tags: c++, sockets, pointers, tcp

(Obvious beginner in c++, keep struggling with pointers)

I've been trying to get the IP address of the client as the server (using TCP), and to save it using a pointer to be able to re-use it later.

In a previous function, I accept the connection and save the **Socket** as `m_clientSocket` and the Socket information in a `struct sockaddr` called `clientaddr`.

Now, I want the next function to return the **client socket** and to save the **source IP**, but the program keeps crashing.

In this last version, I've tried to use a pointer but there's an error in conversion that I can't fix despite my researches.

```
char clientIPaddr[30];
sockaddr_in clientaddr;
SOCKET m_clientSocket;
```

**Function code**

```
SOCKET CmTcpListener::getNewSocket(SOCKET *hSocket, char* ptrSourceIp) 
{
    cout << "Retrieving socket..." << endl;
    if (m_newClientConnection)
    {
        hSocket = &m_clientSocket;

        strcpy(clientIPaddr, inet_ntoa(clientaddr.sin_addr));

        ptrSourceIp = &clientIPaddr;

        cout << "Socket : OK" << endl;

        return *hSocket;
    }
    else {
        cout << "No new client connection." << endl;
        return false;
    }

}
```

**Error**

> c:\work\2015\tcptransport\cmtcplistener.cpp(112) : error C2440: '=' :
> cannot convert from 'char (*)[30]' to 'char *'
> Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast

I'm assuming the rest of the code isn't necessary but if needed I'll be quick to provide it

Comment: I've tried a lot of things and well nothing worked yet but I'd really like to know if there's a really clean (and common) way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit is the line

```
ptrSourceIp = &clientIPaddr;
```

`clientIPaddr` is of type `char[30]`, so the type of `&clientIPaddr` is `char(*)[30]`, i.e. pointer to array of 30 chars. Remove the `&` and you'll be OK, as the name of the array is itself a pointer to its first element (technically, arrays decay to pointers)

```
ptrSourceIp = clientIPaddr;
```

However, right now, you're not doing anything with `ptrSourceIp`, at the end of the function will be unchanged since it is passed by value like any other variable. If you want to modify the passed pointer `ptrSourceIp`, then you need to pass a pointer to it (i.e. a pointer-to-pointer-to-char), so the prototype of your function should be:

```
SOCKET CmTcpListener::getNewSocket(SOCKET *hSocket, char** ptrSourceIp)
```

The second argument you pass has to be `&your_passed_ptr_to_char`. Inside your function you can now modify the passed pointer like

```
*ptrSourceIp = clientIpAddr; // now we modify it
```

Comment: Yes that's what I was doing earlier but then as I tried to simply print the value of ptrSourceIp outside of the function (in the main) right after the function call, the program just crashes.

Could it have something to do with leaked memory? (I'm using a msdn method to detect those and I don't have any "positive" answer)

Comment: Indeed, it isn't. I need to work on those pointers and I should manage to get the value out of this function.

Comment: @PierrickCoquil if you need to modify the pointer, then pass a pointer to pointer, see the updated edit.

Comment: Thanks it's working with the pointer to pointer,
and thank you both for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to assign the address of `clientIPaddr` to a `char*`. It is of the type `char[30]`, so taking the address gives a pointer to a `char` array, not a pointer to a `char`. Arrays can decay to pointers, so just directly assign it:

```
ptrSourceIp = clientIPaddr;
```